# Reading a JSON with multiple nested lists and transforming into a DataFrama

Tags: python, pandas

I have a JSON inside a list. And this JSON have lists inside of lists. Something like that:

```
my data = [{'page': 1,
  'page_size': 100,
  'total_pages': 11,
  'total_results': 1057,
  'items': [{'jw_entity_id': 'ts88361',
    'id': 88361,
    'title': 'Love, Death & Robots',
    'object_type': 'show',
    'scoring': [{'provider_type': 'imdb:votes', 'value': 131937},
     {'provider_type': 'tmdb:score', 'value': 8.2},
     {'provider_type': 'imdb:score', 'value': 8.4}]},
   {'jw_entity_id': 'tm374139',
    'id': 374139,
    'title': 'Sonic - O Filme',
    'object_type': 'movie',
    'scoring': [{'provider_type': 'tmdb:id', 'value': 454626},
     {'provider_type': 'imdb:score', 'value': 6.5},
     {'provider_type': 'tmdb:score', 'value': 7.4}]
```

I managed to transform it into a DataFrame, but one of the column `scoring/provider_type` still with values nested. How can I "unpack" that list and integrate into de DataFrame?

```
from pandas import json_normalize

df = pd.concat([json_normalize(entry, 'items') 
                     for entry in my_data])
```

This is what I get now:

[image: My dataframe]

```
{'jw_entity_id': {0: 'ts88361', 1: 'tm374139'},
 'id': {0: 88361, 1: 374139},
 'title': {0: 'Love, Death & Robots', 1: 'Sonic - O Filme'},
 'object_type': {0: 'show', 1: 'movie'},
 'scoring': {0: [{'provider_type': 'imdb:votes', 'value': 131937},
   {'provider_type': 'tmdb:score', 'value': 8.2},
   {'provider_type': 'imdb:score', 'value': 8.4}],
  1: [{'provider_type': 'tmdb:id', 'value': 454626},
   {'provider_type': 'imdb:score', 'value': 6.5},
   {'provider_type': 'tmdb:score', 'value': 7.4}]}}
```

I need the `scoring` column "unpacked", with the `imdb:score` as a column.

Comment: Correctly space the brackets in my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Structure of your dictionaries in the `scoring` column is a bit convoluted with the repeating keys.
You can concatenate Dataframes created from these lists:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(entry, 'items') 
                     for entry in my_data])

df_scor = pd.concat([
                pd.DataFrame({x['provider_type']: [x['value']]
                    for x in l }
                ) 
                for l in df['scoring'].to_list()
            ]).reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.drop('scoring', axis=1).join(df_scor['imdb:score']) # here we keep only imdb:score

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  jw_entity_id      id                 title object_type  imdb:score
0      ts88361   88361  Love, Death & Robots        show         8.4
1     tm374139  374139       Sonic - O Filme       movie         6.5
```

Comment: Hey, @Tranbi. Thank you! Can you break down a little for me? How did you get the itens for `df_scor`? I ask because in the first `df`, we have `my_data` variable there. In `df_scor` whe have `for x in l` which I don't understand right now – because we didn't assign these variables before and I'm not sure how the code 'knows' that we are reaching to that specific list on the JSON. I'm a beginner, so I hope you can understand my question here. Again, thank you very much

Comment: I used a dictionary comprehension (for x in l) inside a list comprehension (for l in df...). The dictionary comprehension aims at getting the *values* inside each dict and making new dict of it (the original keys are generic and you want them gone)